# Why isn't python featured?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

The site says Python is the preferred language for new Ubuntu applications.  Yet the sdk overview page features QML and HTML5 and presents apis only in those two languages.  Where is the python sdk and the python for ubuntu api?

Answer (score 0):

QML and HTML5 are the preferred languages for writing new applications that can run across devices and form factors. You can certainly use Python, which is still very well supported, but then your apps will only run on the desktop.

Please let us know in which site and where you found the statement that Python is the preferred language for new Ubuntu applications, and we will update it. Thanks!

Comment: Goto resources->programming languages-> python

Comment: In the developer.ubuntu.com